# DynamoDb SDK incomplete scan

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-go

I'm running a webserver which uses the [aws go sdk](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go)

In my `go.mod`:

```
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go v1.30.16
```

I'm attempting to use this library to run a [dynamodb scan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html) across a table:

```golang
    sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String("us-west-2"),
    })

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Create DynamoDB client
    svc := dynamodb.New(sess)

    // snip
    predatesExpirationHorizon := expression.Name(RequestSchema.TimeStamp).BeginsWith("2020-04-27T09")

    projectionExpr := expression.NamesList(
        expression.Name(RequestSchema.PrimaryKey),
        expression.Name(RequestSchema.SortKey),
        expression.Name(RequestSchema.TimeStamp),
        expression.Name(RequestSchema.State),
    )

    expr, err := expression.NewBuilder().
        WithFilter(predatesExpirationHorizon).
        WithProjection(projectionExpr).Build()

    // snip

    params := &dynamodb.ScanInput{
        ExpressionAttributeNames:  expr.Names(),
        ExpressionAttributeValues: expr.Values(),
        FilterExpression:          expr.Filter(),
        ProjectionExpression:      expr.Projection(),
        TableName:                 aws.String(RequestSchema.TableName),
    }

    res, err := svc.Scan(params)

    fmt.Printf("results %v out of %v", *res.Count, *res.ScannedCount)
```

This returns me 2 of the items in my table out of a count of 8010 and the `LastEvaluatedKey` is empty

However, when I attempt to replicate this from the cli I get 3 items back (2 of which are identical) out of 8276

```sh
aws --region us-west-2 dynamodb scan \
     --table-name MyTable \
     --projection-expression '#1, #2, #0, #3' \
     --filter-expression 'begins_with (#0, :0)' \
     --expression-attribute-values '{":0":{"S":"2020-04-27T09"}}' \
     --expression-attribute-names '{"#0":"createdAt","#1":"PK","#2":"SK","#3":"state"}'
```

I dug into the library with the debugger and I can see it's running an http request with a post body of:

```
{"ExpressionAttributeNames":{"#0":"createdAt","#1":"PK","#2":"SK","#3":"state"},
"ExpressionAttributeValues":{":0":{"S":"2020-04-27T09"}},
"FilterExpression":"begins_with (#0, :0)",
"ProjectionExpression":"#1, #2, #0, #3",
"TableName":"MyTable"}
```

This feels extremely unlikely, so I'm assuming I've done something wrong.

When I use the AWS console it's clear that there are 3 matching items.

Some things I've looked at:

- I've double checked my regions are correct and I'm using the same credentials
- I'm aware scans are eventually consistent but these rows haven't been written to in days
- I've tried other versions of the aws go sdk
- I'm querying the same table in the same namespace